# How do I change the windows error sound for windows terminal to something different?

Tags: audio, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

Okay, so you know when you press backspace on an empty line in windows terminal, it makes that annoying error sound? How do I change the sound the something else? Thanks.

Comment: There is not a specific sound for Command or for Windows Terminal.  So you would need to determine which sound and change it to one you like. Control Panel, Sounds. That will affect every app that uses the sound.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for pointing me in that direction, but is it possible to change the critical error sound to something that is not in the list? Thanks.

Comment: @SuperuserUser - Can you be more specific?  Often is the case Windows expects sounds to be a certain format.  Furthermore, there is a good chance, that sounds that are listed are embedded in a single system file

Comment: You can only change the sound setup of what is there. If "nothing" is there, there is nothing to change. As far as I know, only Apps can add Sounds there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Windows Terminal (err, now renamed just "Terminal") 1.13](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.13.11431.0) and later have added an option to set the bell sound directly via the `profile.bellSound` setting.  It can set to a single audio file or an array.  If set to multiple audio files, Terminal will choose one at random for the beep/bell each time it is triggered.

---

###### Previous answer for older versions of Windows Terminal

The Windows Terminal bell is mapped to the *currently assigned* Windows "Critical Stop" sound.  To change the sound you hear for the Windows Terminal Bell, you can change the sound (the `.wav` file) which is mapped to "Critical Stop".

Yes, that `.wav` file can be anywhere on your computer.  To start, press the Windows key or click the Windows "Start" menu, and start typing "change system sounds".  You'll see that entry come up in the menu before you even complete typing it all the way:

[image: Windows Menu Change System Sounds]

From the resulting panel:

[image: Change System Sounds Panel]

Select the "Critical Stop" sound, and then "Browse".  As mentioned, you can browse to any `.wav` file on your PC.

You can also [disable the bell entirely](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-advanced#bell-notification-style) or change it to a visual bell in the latest release (as of about a week ago) of Windows Terminal.  If you have automatic updates on, you probably have it already.

Comment: Man you improve my quality of life, this critical stop default sound was driving me crazy. THANK YOU

Answer (score 10):

Specifically for Ubuntu users of the Win10 terminal, it's possible to turn off the audible and activate the Linux-friendly blinking.

In the Win10 terminal go to Settings > Ubuntu > Advanced > Flash window

[image: replace Windows chime with flashing window]

Comment: A couple of notes on this.  First, I did mention the visual bell as being a new feature (at the time) of Windows Terminal in my answer back in February.  Second, this is *not* specific to Ubuntu.  This works with any Windows Terminal Profile.